# Добавить зацикливание для консольного меню C#

Tags: c#, консоль, menu

**Суть моего вопроса в том, что могу ли я как-то зациклить перемещение по меню (т.е чтобы я не упирался в границы верха и низа, а перескакивал в начало/конец) не переписывая меню с  `case` на `if'ы`**

У меня есть код моего консольного меню (если что на gitlab'e есть проект, скину если нужно):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                DrawMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);
                switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        if (index < Menu.menuItems.Length - 1 || index == Menu.menuItems.Length)
                            index++;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        if (index > 0)
                            index--;
                            break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                        switch (index)
                        { 
                            case 0:
                                PrintPeopleList(readedPeople);
                                ReturnToMainMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                PrintTimelineList(readedTimeline);
                                ReturnToMainMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                PrintNamesPeople();
                                ReturnToMainMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                PrintDeltaTimeline();
                                ReturnToMainMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                AddNewEvent(readedPeople);
                                ReturnToMainMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                AddNewPeople(readedPeople);
                                Console.WriteLine("Человек успешно добавлен!");
                                ReturnToMainMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                Console.WriteLine("Выбран выход из приложения");
                                return;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

И метод для того, чтобы видеть перемещение по меню:

```
        static void DrawMenu(string[] items, int index)
        {
            ClearScreen();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == index)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(items[i]);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Меню состоит из 6 пунктов, их могу прикрепить, если нужно, но чтобы вопрос был совсем огромным, пока упущу.

Comment: Добавьте проверку для своего меню, если при нажатии на стрелочку вниз индекс текущего выбранного элемента меню равен максимальной длине списка, то возвращайте нулевой элемент и наоборот

Comment: `ReturnToMainMenu(Menu.menuItems, index);` настораживает, не рекурсия ли у вас бесконечная здесь. Но не зная кода - не понять. В общем, если у вас там внутри снова вызов `Main()`, то так делать нельзя.

Comment: @aepot Нет, там не вызов `Main(0)` это возвращение по индексу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это должно было быть просто.

```cs
case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
    if (index < Menu.menuItems.Length - 1)
        index++;
    else
        index = 0;
    break;
case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
    if (index > 0)
        index--;
    else
        index = Menu.menuItems.Length - 1;
    break;
```

Кстати, вот это вот `|| index == Menu.menuItems.Length` я не понимаю, зачем.

Comment: Ой, это я пытался придумать что-то и забыл удалить, бессмысленно, согласен

Comment: Это, то, что нужно и просто, спасибо большое! Я не подумал про else, все пытался использовать еще одно условие, а case же не позволяет, пытался даже метод создать `с if'ом`